# Distance transform :

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Kindly help me with the working of Distance transform and rectify the errors. I have tried Borgefors' method which has defined values for Eucledian measure. I get all zeros as output.

Below is the code which i have tried.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat v = imread("ref.png", 0);
    imshow("input", v);

    Mat forward = (Mat_<uchar>(5, 5) << 0, 11, 0, 11, 0, 11, 7, 5, 7, 11, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Mat backward = (Mat_<uchar>(5, 5) << 0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0,  11, 7, 5, 7, 11,  0, 11, 0, 11, 0);

    Mat op = cv::Mat::zeros(v.size(), CV_32FC1);

    cout << forward;
    cout << backward;

    int r = v.rows; 
    int c = v.cols;

    float min=100, x = 0;
    int size = 3;
    int lim = size / 2;
    int a, b;

    for (int i = lim; i <= r-1-lim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = lim; j <= c-1-lim; j++)
        {
            for (int k = -lim; k <= lim; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -lim; l <= lim; l++)
                {
                    a = (v.at<uchar>(i + k, j + l));
                    b=(forward.at<uchar>(k + lim, l + lim));
                    x = a + b;
                    if (x>0 && min> x) 
                        min = x;
                }
            }
            op.at<float>(i, j) = min;
        }
    }

cout << min;
for (int i = (r-1-lim); i >lim; i--)
{
    for (int j = (c-1-lim); j >lim; j--)
    {
        for (int k = -lim; k <= lim; k++)
        {
            for (int l = -lim; l <= lim; l++)
            {
                a = (v.at<uchar>(i + k, j + l));
                b = (forward.at<uchar>(k + lim, l + lim));
                x = a + b;
                if (x >0 && min> x) min = x;
            }
        }
        op.at<float>(i, j) = min;
    }
}
cout << op;


Mat res = cv::Mat::ones(v.size(), CV_8UC1);
normalize(op, res, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
imshow("output",res);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

}

Which is the best method and why it is the best way to implement Distance Transform?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to fix your code:

1. Apply the backward mask in the backward loop, you apply the same mask there as in the forward loop.
2. Use only the defined weights, the values in the mask where you wrote 0 are not part of the mask. Those pixels don't have a distance of 0!

As for your second question, it's probably out of scope for SO. But what the best method is depends very much on the goal. You have a fast and relatively accurate method here, there are other methods that are exact but more expensive.

Comment: Thanks again Cris! I got the output! Other than the above two suggestions I made some other changes also.